# Use Matplotlib on django site

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, matplotlib, web-frameworks

I am thinking of starting a new django project for plotting stock prices and displaying them onto the site. I know matplotlib pretty well and was wondering if I could plot the chart and somehow push it to the site with the usual matplotlib features like zoom etc.

I have seen this done where that images are pushed but I am wondering if I could push the chart with its functionality provided by matplotlib and I can't seem to find an answer anywhere so maybe it isn't possible?

Answer (score -1):

I've never used it personally, but [mpld3](https://mpld3.github.io/index.html) appears to do what you are asking.